# Detect long press on keyboard key (Ionic, Android)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, input, mobile, keyboard

I have an Ionic (5) app and I want to detect a long press on a key (keyboard) when the app is running on a mobile device (I'm testing on Android).

I added `(keyup)` and `(keydown)` to a `ion-input`, and when I run the app on browser I'm able to get the time difference between the first keydown event (if I long press on a key, keydown is firing multiple times) and the single keyup event that i receive when the key is released.

Unfortunately, this solutions isn't working on mobile (Android), I only receive one keydown event and one keyup event that fire almost at the same time, even if I press the enter key for more than 5 seconds or so.

I don't think any code is needed, since this one is more a conceptual question.

How can detect a long press on a mobile keyboard?

Comment: Just to clarify: my final need is to allow the user to do some advanced operations on input by pressing or holding enter key. The input has already 2 buttons to perform some actions (e.g resetting text and opening a modal with a list of recent elements the user can select to autocomplete input) and I don't want to place too many buttons near the input. So I wanted to perform some actions with keyboard. I would need a sort of special functions, but the only one I can think of is using enter or shift+enter. But shift key would be nasty if the user has to type other text.

Comment: Can you think of some nice way to use keyboard to perform some nice actions? I know that a mobile keyboard is not intended to use F1, CTRL or whatever but maybe it has been implemented in other ways

Comment: Keyboards on a mobile phone really aren't designed to do this.  Particulalry not on Android, I know less about the iOS keyboard framework. ALso, things like shift enter won't work on Android either-  no keyboard reports the shift state, that's an implementation detail of the keyboard.  Nor will control-  no keyboard I know has it, and even if they did they wouldn't report key events so a hold and press of another button wouldn't work for an app.

Comment: I'd really move away from thinking of things keyboard centric at all-  that makes sense at a PC where you have a keyboard in front of you at all times and its your primary input device.  On a mobile device where the keyboard is hidden at all times when not editing text, touch is the primary input.  If you're afraid of too many options, consider a menu button where tapping it opens a menu of choices.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I thought about a menu but I wanted something faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android this isn't going to work.  It's just not how the keyboard interface happens.  By and large, keyboards don't actually send key events in Android.  They send commitText messages, which just send a string to the text field.  Anything turning it into key up and key down events is in the Ionic framework.  Since the keyboard doesn't send key events, the app can't know how long they pressed the button.  They keyboard doesn't send that info.  So the Ionic framework that's making the key events can't give you that info either, there's no data for it to extrapolate from.

You're going to have to come up with a different UX design, this will never work on Android.